# Left skewed data generator (Excel)

Tags: excel, statistics

I am looking for a function in excel that will allow me to generator left skewed data with the option of picking a mean and standard deviation.

E.g If I want to generate 5 numbers with SD 2 and mean 45  , it must be 43,44,45,46,47.

I would also like to be able to pick the upper and lower limit. I don't want 0,44,46,46,90

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an Excel question (i.e. it has nothing to do with Excel).
I don't think there's a standard function in any application or language that will give you what you need, you're basically asking for someone to develop an algorithm for you. If you want to do this in Excel you need some VBA code..

I don't mind having a crack at the algorithm but you need to be more specific with your parameters..

are there always 5 numbers returned? (this simplifies it hugely)
do they have to be integers?

also the SD of 43,44,45,46,47 is 1.414 not 2, 2 is the variance